# Sign in with Google: Show user's image

Tags: jquery, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I'm trying to display a user's profile picture, after they signed in with Google.

I'm using this jQuery code to add an attribute to the image with id #g-image:

```
$("#g-image").attr('src', profile.getImageUrl());
```

The image tag looks like this:

```
<img id="g-image" class="inline-block h-9 w-9 rounded-full" src="" alt="profile">
```

This method does work for displaying the name: $("#g-name").text(profile.getName());

But it doesn't for the profile image.

Comment: Are you sure the account has an image?

Comment: Yes, it does. The image is displayed just fine in any other Google service.